# Drupal delete a field instance for node

Tags: file, drupal, field

How do i delete a field instance for a node. I use this field for file attachments for a node.

When i update the node with removed attachment that field is not there in the updated node , but node_save doesn't delete the entry from the table for that field.

So is there some api which deletes it from the node.

THanks,

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a field instance means removing that *field_name* field and its data from a given *bundle*, meaning every field *field_name* attached to the given *bundle* will be removed.

You don't want to remove all node attachment but one specificly. Here an example of how to delete a file attachment field for a specific entity ($node) :

```
// Optionally : Load file object.
$filefoo = file_load($node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][$fid]);

// Remove the field value from $node.
unset($node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]);

// Save the entity
entity_save('node', $node);

// Optionally : safely delete the file (won't be deleted if still in use)
file_delete($filefoo);
```

Comment: I just want to delete it for an specific node id. Can I do that using the above function?

Comment: No!!! Do not use `field_delete_instance()` nor `field_delete_field()` to delete a specific node field. There was a misunderstanding but I updated my answer, it's clearer now.

Comment: Yeah the problem is this is what I am doing, like before I save the node i the field array is not present. But after I save the node the entry for that node from the fields table doesn't go away. So basically the node_save() doesnot take care of removing the entry for that node from the fields table. So i am looking for some other api to get rid of the field

Comment: The problem is precisely that since the field is not present when saving the node it is not updated. You have to unset the field value, not the field. `$node->field_name` have to be set with an empty value so that the change can be saved.

Comment: May be i dont understand , but unset is used to unset something which is set. If I dont have any $node->field_name(field_name is not part of the node object), how would i use unset($node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]);

Comment: You're right (I thought you did unset the entire field from the node). Like I said the field must be present with an empty value before saving $node : `$node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array();`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a weird thing but it works fine. I have run this multiple times and it clears the field column        if(!isset($entity->field_files)){
    // unset the field value from $node.
      unset($entity->field_files[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]);
   } I check if field_files is set . if not the i unset an array within field_files. Its weird but it works , do you know what is possible explanation for this. Again thanks a lot for your help

Comment: This is just an assumption : When an entity is updated, all attached fields loaded along with the $entity object are updated as well. I think fields that are not present can't be updated because the field API can't guess if such fields have to be deleted, emptied or untouched. This behavior should allow us to save an entity without having to load all its field, preventing non-loaded fields to be deleted. That's why we have to set an empty value into the $entity->field (equivalent to unset $entity->field[$any_value]) rather than unset the field from the entity.